# Remove function list from doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm running into a problem with the doxygen documentation.
In the "Files" section, is it possible to remove the functions list at the top of the page with a flag in the doxyfile ?
If not, is there a way to insert a section (with a doxygen command in my source code in cpp) before this "Functions" list.

Comment: Can you post some code?  what have you try?

Comment: I just set a .cpp file as the input source code. The code is a set of tests using BOOST_TEST_CASE methods. I use the \test command to document my tests. I set the tag EXTRACT_ALL to YES and the others to NO in the doxyfile. I think I disable most of the SHOW_XX tags. But I didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `NO`.

Set `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS` to `YES`.

Don't document the members you want hidden.

You can also use `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` to exclude some documented items:
The EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag can be used to specify one or more symbol names (namespaces, classes, functions, etc.) that should be excluded from the output. The symbol name can be a fully qualified name, a word, or if the wildcard * is used, a substring. Examples: ANamespace, AClass, AClass::ANamespace, ANamespace::*Test

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this documentation page:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html

Chapter "Changing the layout of pages" explains how to include/exclude and more generally organize your generated documentation. I had a problem like yours, if I correctly understand, and followed the steps indicated in the above mentioned documentation:

1) By using command "doxygen -l", I obtained a standard "DoxygenLayout.xml" layout file

2) Prepared a custom layout file, by modifying the standard one, by commenting out the whole <memberdecl>...</memberdecl> XML section

3) In my Doxyfile, specified the custom layout file as a value for option "LAYOUT_FILE"

Careful with paths, so that doxygen knows where to find the Doxyfile and the custom layout file.